# Как вывести перебор элементов максимально разным и НЕ по порядку?

Tags: python, комбинаторика, перебор

Имеется 3 списка. Надо их перебрать с максимальным отличием. Я пробовал отсортировать по количеству элементов и потом перемножить, но повторение с предыдущим все равно получается:

```
from itertools import product
the_list = [[111, 182], [264,4, 271], [48, 98, 104, 134, 141, 143, 180, 213, 225, 244, 278]]
the_list = sorted(the_list, key=len, reverse=True)
for i in list(product(*the_list)):
    print(i)
```

Как перебрать их с максимальным отличием (чтобы не for-перебор был)? Очередность примерного перебора на картинке показал.

!Дополнение:

1. рандомность не нужна
2. Я нашел закономерноть!!! Во-общем, тут такая схема: нужно брать каждые `len(lstK1)*len(lstK2)*..*len(lstKN-1) + len(lstKN-1)+1, если len(lstN)>1`. Причем итераций будет столько, сколько комбинаций!

Теперь вопрос. Есть такая библиотека, которая делает копию списка в таком порядке?

[image: Примерная очередность]

Comment: Ну третье значение по-вашему какое? Потому как в третьем столбце различные элементы уже закончились.

Comment: Я понимаю, что тут обычный for-перебор, но мне надо чтоб очередность примерна такая как я указал - максимально разные

Comment: Высоким слогом: требуется найти гамильтонов путь в декартовом произведении множеств с максимальной суммой расстояний Хемминга между элементами. Если все размеры множеств взаимно просты - решение понятно. Если нет, начинается интересное. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если длины подсписков не кратны, то, как мне кажется, подойдёт вот такой вариант.

```
# from math import prod    # Python 3.8+
from numpy import prod
the_list = [[111, 182], [264,4, 271], [48, 98, 104, 134, 141, 143, 180, 213, 225, 244, 278]]
prod_lengths = prod(list(map(len, the_list)))
result = list(zip(*(x*(prod_lengths//len(x)) for x in the_list)))
```

Или через генератор, чтобы не занимать память размножением списков.

```
def get_combination(*args):
    for i in range(prod(list(map(len, the_list)))):
        yield tuple(lst[i%len(lst)] for lst in args)

result = list(get_combination(*the_list))
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! А то я вчера уже формулу стал выводить. Кстати, чтобы не было повторений результат еще ко множеству надо привести и тогда все комбинации будут уникальны!

Comment: Кстати, Ваш 1ый способ выводит все комбинации. 2ой способ - выводит дубли и из-за них получается в 2раза меньше комбинаций. Поэтому 1ый вариант - то, что надо! Спасибо!

Comment: Оба способа дают идентичные результаты (ибо алгоритмически это один и тот же подход). И дают такой же набор, что и `itertools.product`. Вот, проверено assert'ами, можно удостовериться - https://ideone.com/lrORXD  Дубли могут быть только из-за кратности длин массивов. Но они будут у обоих вариантов.