# Комбинации цифр по словарю

Tags: python

Имеется словарь

`d = {'1': [4], '4': [1, 5, 6], '5': [1, 2, 5, 6]}`

Как вывести все комбинации для 1,4,5 (их может быть больше и цифры могут быть другие)?

Например

```
print(4,1,1) и далее

4,5,1
4,6,1
4,1,2,
4,5,2
4,6,2
4,1,5,
4,5,5
4,6,5
4,1,6,
4,5,6
4,6,6
```

Comment: У меня был аналогичный вопрос когда-то - посмотрите  как перебор делается: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1362747/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%9d%d0%95-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ссылке, которой в комментарии указал там при помощи **zip** решилась проблема.

В Вашем случае я понял, что на вход надо подавать ключи словаря и выдавать комбинации значений словаря:

```
from numpy import prod
d = {'1': [4], '4': [1, 5, 6], '5': [1, 2, 5, 6]}
key1, key2, key3 = input().split()

the_list = [d[key1], d[key2], d[key3]]
prod_lengths = prod(list(map(len, the_list)))
result = list(zip(*(x*(prod_lengths//len(x)) for x in the_list)))

for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Если задать:

```
1 5 4
```

Напечатает:

```
(4, 1, 1)
(4, 2, 5)
(4, 5, 6)
(4, 6, 1)
(4, 1, 5)
(4, 2, 6)
(4, 5, 1)
(4, 6, 5)
(4, 1, 6)
(4, 2, 1)
(4, 5, 5)
(4, 6, 6)
```